# iOS: Audio recorded plays fine on Chrome but NOT on Safari

Tags: ios, audio

I am using AVAudioRecorder to record audio on iPhone and then uploading that audio file to a server where it is playable on a website.

The file plays just fine on Chrome, but on Safari it fails to play!

These are the settings I'm using with AVAudioRecorder:

```
let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000.0,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1 as NSNumber,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
        ]
```

This is how I am uploading:

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: audioData, name: "file", fileName: "file.m4a", mimeType: "audio/m4a")
```

I have also tried this but it does NOT work either:

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: audioData, name: "file", fileName: "file.mp4", mimeType: "audio/mp4")
```

Why won't Safari play my file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC instead of kAudioFormatLinearPCM and it will play fine on Safari.